# Find all cssRules that have "body" in the selector

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension that very minutely modifies the CSS of any given page (inserting all of the BODY content on the page into a new DIV, then messing with that DIV in a little bit).  To do this accurately across all cases, I need to find ALL of the CSS rules that reference the "body" element in them.  For example, I would need to grab all of the following:

```
body {//CSS RULES!}

body, p, div, h2 {//CSS RULES/}

body.whatever {//CSS RULES!}

body#myBody {//CSS RULES!}

body>div i {//CSS RULES!}

body div.someDiv {//CSS RULES!}

html>body {//CSS RULES!}

html>body>div.someDiv {//CSS RULES!}

body>div>div>div>div#thisIsTerribleCSS {//CSS RULES!}
```

I understand that some of the above lines of CSS are absoultely terrible and violate all convention, but since this extension isn't aware of who wrote the CSS or how standards compliant it is, it really needs to be able to deal with even the most messed up rule sets.

However, I have a problem in that [chrome and firefox don't allow javascript to parse the cssRules of Cross Domain stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5679309/2230156).  So, if the author of the website links to some external resource without modifying their server's CORS settings, those cssRules are opaque to javascript.  Is there any way to access them and view ALL of the cssRules affecting a page?

Comment: `document.stytlesheets.cssRules` But yes you are right. It won't read the cross domain CSS rules.

Comment: Is Cross domain CSS files your problem ?

Comment: @blunderboy, yes that is exactly the issue.  I want to grab the cssRules, even from cross-domain css files.

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow load the contents of these external CSS files via Ajax as a text string?  If I could get the file content, I'm sure I could parse the string to get the rules I need.