# Getting and changing CSS attributes with javascript without looking at a particular element

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking for a way to get a page's css with js without looking at a particular element, and then change the CSS rules rather than the CSS for different elements.

For instance, let say I want to change the background color of all elements that have a blue bg to red, and that after that some new elements might be created. I'd like to find all the css classes with blue bg and change them to red. `document.styleSheets` doesn't seem to work that well:

For this page I tried this in the console. It doesn't log anything.

```
var logAttr = function(classes){
    if(classes !== null){
        for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            for(var attr in classes[i].style){
                console.log(attr);
            }
        }
    }
};

for(var sheets_idx = 0; sheets_idx < document.styleSheets.length; sheets_idx++){
    logAttr(document.styleSheets[sheets_idx].rules);
    logAttr(document.styleSheets[sheets_idx].cssRules);
}
```

`document.styleSheets[0].rules` and `document.styleSheets[0].document.styleSheets` are null...

Comment: Why doesn't `document.styleSheets` seem to work that well? What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that stylesheets do work well, probably you just didn't manage to get your example working: take a look at [this](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets).

```
var sheet = (function() {
    // Create the <style> tag
    var style = document.createElement("style");

    // Add a media (and/or media query) here if you'd like!
    // style.setAttribute("media", "screen")
    // style.setAttribute("media", "only screen and (max-width : 1024px)")

    // WebKit hack :(
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));

    // Add the <style> element to the page
    document.head.appendChild(style);

    return style.sheet;
})();
```

That creates a stylesheet for you with all of the right conditions to work in.
Now, to insert a rule in string form, you simply use this thing:

```
sheet.insertRule('div {position: absolute; top:0px; width:10vh; height:10vw;}')
```

In case you simply want to add a rule to an existing ruleset:

```
sheet.addRule('div', 'background-color: red');
```

If you want to use a custom function to do this, simply call sheet.addRule with certain arguments:

```
function add(query, property){

    //don't forget that you need to have already created the sheet!
    sheet.addRule(query, property);
}
```

The query can be anything accessible through css: `.class, #id, h1, #id > h1 > .class`

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer on how to change CSS rules! It seems that the reason `document.styleSheets` is not working is discussed here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678040/cssrules-rules-are-null-in-chrome)