# chrome disable web security safety incognito vm

Tags: google-chrome, security, virtual-machine, xss, same-origin-policy

I'm working on a project that requires me to use chrome to visit hundreds of websites with the --disable-web-security flag.  As far as I understand, enabling this flag will disable the same origin policy.  I can't, however, find information regarding whether other browser security measures such as XSS auditing are disabled as well.  Does the --disable-web-security flag only apply to the same origin policy?

If indeed this flag only applies to the same origin policy, would I then be safe to browse with it enabled as long as I am in a new incognito session?  If not, would browsing within a virtual machine provide complete protection?

EDIT: I also will not be inputing any personal information while this flag is enabled.

Comment: I'll take the role of the annoying person that asks why you need to disable-web-security. Is it not possible to achieve what you need by writing a simple chrome extension?

Comment: Also note that you can start Chrome using --user-data-dir to specify separate data directories for each instance, thus nothing is shared between the launches.

Comment: @Erlend, I need access to cross-domain resources within the browser environment, and as far as I can tell, a Chrome extension does not provide a solution.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678040/cssrules-rules-are-null-in-chrome)